# Is there any way to run a secondary python script at regular intervals to work on output of a primary script in Slurm?

Tags: python, shell, slurm

I am submitting a batch script that involves a primary command/script (an mpi process) that outputs data and I need to evaluate the progress of the primary process by running a secondary Python script at fixed intervals of time when the primary process is still running. Is there any command that would allow me to do so this with a Slurm batch script?

As an example, consider the primary process takes 24 hours, if I place the Python script normally after the end of the primary command/script, it would only run at the end of the primary process. I need the Python command/script to run every 1 hour to process data generated by the primary process. Is this possible on Slurm?

Comment: What about cron?

Comment: cron is not an option, it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the script would look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
#SBATCH ...
#SBATCH ...

while : ; do sleep 3600 ; python <secondary script> ; done &

mpirun <primary command>
```

The idea is to run the secondary script in an infinite loop in the background. When the primary command finishes, the job is terminated and the background loop is stopped.